# How can I use CONCAT in JOIN conditions with CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working on a CakePHP 3.0 backend where I have the following tables : '*prescriptions*' and '*profils*' (names are french).

'*prescriptions*' has a foreign key directed to '*profils*' : ***prescriptions.profils_id***.

'profils' has two fields that can be searched : 'nom' and 'prenom'

The relationship has been declared like this :

```
class PrescriptionsTable extends Table
{    
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('prescriptions');
        $this->belongsTo('Profils', [
            'foreignKey' => 'profils_id',
        ]);
     }
}

class ProfilsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('profils');
        $this->hasMany('Prescriptions', [
            'foreignKey' => 'profils_id',
        ]);
    }
}
```

The *PrescriptionsController* has a *search* action where the user can set various filters. The ones I am working on allows him to search a Prescription after a substring of the name of the person (Profil) owning that Prescription.

Thus, '**al**' could match 'Albert Dupont' or 'Marc Vidal' but not 'Eugène Brun'. Likewise, '**ert dup**' should match 'Albert Dupont' (as '**ont Al**' should', but that's another story).

The ***search()*** method has the following lines for the query :

```
$q1 = $this->Prescriptions->find()->where(['Prescriptions.users_id = ' . $userId]);

$q1->matching('Profils', function ($q) use($filter) {
                return $q->where(["CONCAT(Profils.prenom, ' ', Profils.nom) like" => "%$filter%"]);
});
[...]
return $q1->select(['id'])->toArray();
```

Unfortunately when I run the query, CakePHP throws me the following error :

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'profils.nom' in 'on clause'

I wanted to check the query object so I tried  :

```
$q1->matching('Profils', function ($q) use($filter) {
                    return $q->where(["CONCAT(Profils.prenom, ' ') like" => "%$filter%"]);
```

which is obvously not a very interesting CONCAT, but it works. The error only rises when I use two fields : the second one does not use the alias Profils but the table name 'profils' instead.

I've been stuck on this error for several hours now and I'll appreciate any insights on what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Since it says the error is in `on clause`, is there a place where you might be performing a JOIN and maybe that is failing ?

Comment: I may be wrong because I have no experience on CakePHP and I had to work on this code at an emergency. As far as I understand the docs, the matching() function handles the join.

Comment: Does `Profils` table have a `nom` column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The used syntax isn't ment to support that

The syntax that you are using is ment to support constructs like

```
TableAlias.column SQL_EXPRESSION
```

The compiler will lowercase the expression part, ie everything found after a possible `TableAlias.column` identifier, so in your case `CONCAT(Profils.prenom,` will be treated as the identifier, and the rest that is being seen as separated via whitespace, `' ', Profils.nom) like`, is being treated as the expression (neither is being checked for validity), hence being lowercased, and that's where it happens, the finaly query will look for `profils.nom`, which doesn't exist, as the alias is `Profils`.

### Use expressions

You should use proper expressions, they are portable, combinable, and support value binding.

CakePHP ships with support for various SQL functions out the box, including `CONCAT`. It also supports various comparison expressions that can be combined with other expressions, ie you can simply pass a `concat` function expression to a `like` comparison expression and you should be good:

```
return $q
    ->where(function (\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp, \Cake\ORM\Query $query) use($filter) {
        return $exp
            ->like(
                $query->func()->concat([
                    'Profils.prenom' => 'identifier',
                    ' ',
                    'Profils.nom' => 'identifier'
                ]),
                "%$filter%",
                'string'
            );
    });
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression::like()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.Expression.QueryExpression.html#_like)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\FunctionsBuilder::concat()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.FunctionsBuilder.html#_concat)**

Comment: I had to use 'literal' instead of 'identifier' because the 'identifier' type was giving me queries like : SELECT Prescriptions.id AS `Prescriptions__id` FROM prescriptions Prescriptions LEFT JOIN profils Profils ON Profils.id = (Prescriptions.profils_id) WHERE (Prescriptions.users_id = 190 AND (CONCAT('identifier', ' ', 'identifier')) LIKE '%whatever%'). Anyway, thanks for this detailed answer, you saved my day :o)

Comment: @ChristopheBrun That shouldn't happen, `identifier` should be the way to go as it supports automatic quoting. I've tested the code with the latest CakePHP 3.3.8 and it works just fine.